# ResponseBody inconsistent JSON string (OKHttp 3.10.0)

Tags: java, json, okhttp

Firstly I searched about this issue but couldn't find any solution.

I am sending a POST request to a web service. This web service returns response but I see that the response is not complete.

With PostMan I get full response without issue. But OKHttp cuts the response.

```
    public List<Product> getProducts(String token, long bill_acct_id, long customer_id, Context context) {
    if(token != null && !token.equals("")) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        List<Product> prods;
        Map<String, String> list_of_headers = new HashMap<>();
        list_of_headers.put("WSC-AUTH-TOKEN", token);
        list_of_headers.put("Accept", "application/json, text/plain, */*");
        list_of_headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
        Headers headers = Headers.of(list_of_headers);
        try {
            Response response = RequestSender.post2("URL", "{\"billingAccountId\":\""+bill_acct_id+"\", \"customerId\":\""+customer_id+"\"}", headers, context);
            int returnCode = response.code();
            ResponseBody body = response.body();
            Log.e("INFO", body.string());
            if (returnCode == 200) {
                prods = gson.fromJson(body.string(), new TypeToken<List<Product>>() {
                }.getType());

                return prods;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("Error", ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

The response:

- Solved.

Response from Postman:

- Solved

Anyone faced this issue? I need your help. Thanks.

**EDIT: ** Actually it was complete. Log.e() and System.out.println(); methods doesn't show complete JSON.

Comment: Really! Can you please use developer's tool to confirm this?

Comment: How to use developer's tool? I didn't use before.

Comment: In Chrome, press F12 > Network and you can see the AJAX requests that you are sending. It shows the response from the server. There should not be any inconsistency.

Comment: The problem is not with Chrome. I use OkHTTP on an android application. Inconsistency happening in ResponseBody object.

Comment: Check that your web service is populating the `Content-length` header correctly

Comment: paulturnip could you show me an example?

Comment: A well behaved HTTP client will always use this header if provided and a well behaved http endpoint will always populate it.  in postman you can inspect the http response headers.    https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#page-30

Comment: These are response headers. I took from Chrome Dev Tools.

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Headers: RN,WSC-AUTH-TOKEN, Origin, Accept, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET,PUT, DELETE,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: WSC-AUTH-TOKEN
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 31 May 2018 13:13:00 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Server: Apache/2.4.20 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Comment: In the request header Content-Length is 32 but when I set this key/value pair in OkHttp request it gives me an error about content-length.